Images are showing up as blank in Web Outlook, rendering properly among other apps, including desktop Outlook
My email is showing images correctly in all mailboxes and platforms except Web (browser) Outlook, where they are simply rendered blank. The "image" is still clickable, and takes up space on the email, but the image is not there, just white.
I checked for any display:none attributes, double checked width/max width and that the sizes all aligned properly within the tables. (It is email development so it is using tables for everything). Here is some relevant affected code
<!-- MODULE BEGINS // -->
<tr>
 <td align="center" valign="top"><!-- CENTERING TABLE // -->
  <table style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td align="center" valign="top">

       <!-- FLEXIBLE CONTAINER // -->
        <table class="flexibleContainer" style="width: 640px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
           <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td class="flexibleContainerCellFull" width="640" align="center"  valign="top">

                    <!-- CONTENT TABLE // --> 
                    <!-- The table cell imageContent has padding applied to the bottom as part of the framework, ensuring images space correctly in Android Gmail.-->
                   <table style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tbody>
                         <tr>
                            <td class="imageContent" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom:10px;" valign="top">
                            <a href="LINK">
                                <img class="flexibleImage" style="max-width: 640px;"src="http://support.amrevmuseum.org/images/content/pagebuilder/Untitled_design__31__1__1_.png" alt=""width="640" />
                           </a>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                   <!-- // CONTENT TABLE -->
                   
               </td>
              </tr>
             </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- // FLEXIBLE CONTAINER -->

          </td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
      <!-- // CENTERING TABLE -->
      </td>
      </tr>


And here is the relevant CSS
 table[id="emailBody"],
        table[class="flexibleContainer"] {
            width: 100% !important;
        }
    
.flexibleContainerCellFull {
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-Right: 0px;
        padding-Left: 0px;
    }

.imageContent {
        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }

.flexibleImage {
        height: auto;
    }



My guess is that this has nothing to do with CSS but that you are trying to load an img with http into a secure (ie loaded with https) system. Try loading an img that can be served with https and see if that makes a difference.

^ that's a known Outlook.com thing. Also, try not using square brackets and use the normal CSS style for  table[id="emailBody"], table[class="flexibleContainer"].

@AHaworth Yep this was the issue. Thank you!
